# How to authenticate Sails JS application using Passport?

Tags: node.js, authentication, sails.js, passport.js

I am using Sails v0.10.5. I want to integrate an authentication system with username and password using Passport. For that I was going through the following documentations:

- [[How To] Implement Passport.js Authentication with Sails.js](http://www.geektantra.com/2013/08/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js/)
- [CREATING A SAILS APPLICATION USING PASSPORT AUTHENTICATION](http://blog.thesparktree.com/post/77311774912/creating-a-sails-application-using-passport)

But, I have seen in the comments that these are outdated and no longer works with sails v0.10.5. I tried these, it was not authenticating and I was able to access all the controller actions without any authentication.

Is there any updated version or any other useful documentation for integrating?

Comment: See my comment below about what I did to solve this problem https://github.com/carlospliego/sails-token-auth-setup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly advise you to try [sails-generate-auth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth) generator. It is based on passport and it creates whole authentication layer for your sails.js application including local policy (user/password), OAuth2.0 and OpenID.

Sails-generate-auth will create for you two new models (User, Passport), authentication controller, service, configure routes and policies. 
So if you want to apply authentication to your existing application it would be safer to create fresh sails application, generate authentication layer using *sails-generate-auth*, test it a little bit and then copy necessary files to your original application.

Hope that helps.

**Edit**

[sails-auth](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth) is also a good solution. Similarily to sails-generate-auth, it generates all necessary models and services so you can connect it easily to your existing service.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try this.

Comment: I tried sails-generate-auth. I have configured everything as mentioned in their documentation. But when I lift the server, it's not working. I was able to access all the controllers. Here is a sample app: [sails-passport](https://github.com/sahanDissanayake/sails-passport). This also has the same problem when I tried. Any idea why it is happening? I am using local strategy for authentication

Comment: It worked! And I got answer for the question in the above comment. Passport doesn't have a policy to deny access to the controller. I have to create another policy for that.

Comment: Any suggestions as sails-generate-auth is starting to get abandoned and hasn't had any meaningful updates in months?

Comment: @ShawnStrickland I've just edited my answer. Please check [sails-auth](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth).

Answer (score 2):

Check out this easy to use example for **sails.js** with **passport.js** supporting both Email, Twitter and Facebook: https://github.com/bmustata/sails-auth-super-template

Answer (score 0):

After testing sails-generate-auth, sails-auth and waterlock, I found that all those solutions either try to do too much or doesn't do everything correctly. I then decided to help out a bit and write some instructions on how this can be done. Ive been using these steps for a while now.

Step 1 ( Globals ): `$ npm install -g sails`

Step 2 ( App ): `$ sails new myApp`

Step 3 ( Files ): Copy every file in `https://github.com/carlospliego/sails-token-auth-setup` to its corresponding folder

Step 4 ( Policies ): Add this code to your `config/policies.js`

```
 '*': "hasToken",
 UserController: {
    "create": true
 },
 AuthController: {
    '*': true
 }
```

Step 5: change the value of `config/tokenSecret.js`

Step 6: ( Dependencies )

```
npm install --save passport
npm install --save passport-local
npm install --save bcrypt-nodejs
npm install --save jsonwebtoken
npm install --save express-jwt
```

---

Your endpoints will look like this:

- `POST/GET/PUT/DELETE user/`
- `POST auth/login`
- `DELETE auth/logout`

---

Here is a great guide on how to create token based authentication in sails: https://github.com/carlospliego/sails-token-auth-setup